# How does enumFromTo work?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I cannot add a number to a `Char`; the following will fail to compile `'a' + 1`. But yet, `['a'..'z']` successfully creates a string in which each of the character value is incremented. Is there a special function that can increment a `Char`?

I know that I can do `chr (ord c + 1)`.

How does the `['a'..'z']` or the underlying `enumFromTo` function increment the characters in the resulting `String`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a special function that can add to a `Char`, from the same `Enum` class that `enumFromTo` is from, named `succ`. Beware that it is partial: `succ maxBound` is undefined, so take care to check the value of the character before you apply `succ`. `succ` is indeed the same as `\c -> chr (ord c + 1)`, as you can verify with the `universe` package:

```
> let avoidMaxBound f x = if x == maxBound then Nothing else Just (f x)
> avoidMaxBound succ == avoidMaxBound (\c -> chr (ord c + 1))
True
```

In fact the [implementation of `succ` in GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#Enum) is quite close to the function you suggested:

```
instance  Enum Char  where
    succ (C# c#)
       | isTrue# (ord# c# /=# 0x10FFFF#) = C# (chr# (ord# c# +# 1#))
       | otherwise             = error ("Prelude.Enum.Char.succ: bad argument")
```

However, `succ` is not used in the implementation of `enumFromTo` in GHC:

```
instance  Enum Char  where
    {-# INLINE enumFromTo #-}
    enumFromTo (C# x) (C# y) = eftChar (ord# x) (ord# y)
{-# RULES
"eftChar"       [~1] forall x y.        eftChar x y       = build (\c n -> eftCharFB c n x y)
#-}

-- We can do better than for Ints because we don't
-- have hassles about arithmetic overflow at maxBound
{-# INLINE [0] eftCharFB #-}
eftCharFB :: (Char -> a -> a) -> a -> Int# -> Int# -> a
eftCharFB c n x0 y = go x0
                 where
                    go x | isTrue# (x ># y) = n
                         | otherwise        = C# (chr# x) `c` go (x +# 1#)

{-# NOINLINE [1] eftChar #-}
eftChar :: Int# -> Int# -> String
eftChar x y | isTrue# (x ># y ) = []
            | otherwise         = C# (chr# x) : eftChar (x +# 1#) y
```

If you can squint past the nastiness that exists primarily for efficiency reasons, you can see that `eftChar` is essentially using `succ`, but an inlined version of it rather than an actual call to `succ` (here, to avoid boxing and re-boxing the `Char` being manipulated).

Comment: I think he wanted to know about `succ` and `pred` and how they operate on `Enum` types. I didn't understand that from his initial question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the `pred` and `succ` methods, which return the predecessor or successor of `Enum a`. The problem is that for a `Bounded` `Enum`, if you apply `succ` on the maximum member of the set you will get an error.

Bearing this in mind, you can define `enumFromTo` recursively as so (avoiding dangerous `succ` calls):

```
eftEnum :: (Enum a, Eq a, Ord a) => a -> a -> [a]
eftEnum a b 
    | a  > b = []
    | a == b = [a]
    | otherwise = a : rest 
        where rest = eftEnum (succ a) b
```